# C# - Как открыть страницу в браузере и затем нажать на кнопку?

Tags: c#, .net

Мне нужно зайти на главную страницу сайта, затем нажать на кнопку, после чего откроется новая страница. На новой странице мне нужно нажать другую кнопку и посмотреть открылась ли форма.


Получается мне нужно как-то эмулировать веб-браузер?

Comment: _посмотреть открылась ли форма_ => где открылась форма ? (повесив Event => Navigation не поможет ?)

Comment: Сайт парсите? Если да - работайте с сервером, а не с UI мордой, изучите запросы, повторите их, перенесите в C#, готово. Если сайт дает только HTML, то разбирайте его также, через C#, а не эмуляцией браузера. Если вы пишете тесты для своего сайта, то используйте Селениум.

Comment: "...то используйте Селениум" - или Playwright

Answer (score 0):

1. Если в исходном HTML коде сайта (`Ctrl+U`) уже есть форма, то и ссылку можно вытащить легко. UPD. В ответе сервера смотрим наличие формы после перехода по ссылке.
2. Если формы нет или ссылку так не вытащить. То нужно через инспектор хрома (`F12` -> `Network`) посмотреть запрос и ответ на него, так можно увидеть и как вызвать форму (если ее нет сразу), и что происходит при нажатии. Вот те же самые запросы программа должна посылать.
3. Есть возможность использовать WebDriver и подобные решения, которые созданы для тестирования, но такую задачу решают, потому что вызывают управляемый из кода экземпляр браузера